# How to check whether facebook have secret traffic during idle time?

Tags: network-traffic

I would like to use some tool such as wireshark, to check that whether facebook have some secret internet traffic to and from my computer. I would like to do this to make sure facebook doesn't consume up my bandwidth.
I am behind a proxy server which acts as a gateway, that is, all my packet are sent to the proxy before going out. Is there any method to check for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook, like all Web 2.0 sites, uses asynchronous calls to update your web browser.

In other words, expect it to use bandwidth if the site is open, even if it appears to be idle.

To monitor this, use [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

Comment: I would to ask that how to check the bandwidth consumed by facebook secretly in 1 day. Thanks.

Comment: I'm confused by your use of the word "secretly". There is no secret.

Comment: I mean when the browser is idle.

Comment: As I pointed out, because of the asynchronous nature of the website, the browser is never idle.

Comment: So when I am in the facebook page, how much bandwidth facebook is consuming using ajax? How can I check that? When I use wireshark I don't really which packet is for facebook.

Comment: You'll have to have some sort of tool that captures your bandwidth (WireShark for example), and then review the packets to and from Facebook and count how many there are. You'd be able to identify traffic from Facebook by its IP address.

Comment: In any event, most of the AJAX is text, so you're not using that much. If you're really worried about the bandwidth bill, close the web browser.